# Python find peaks of distribution

Tags: python, math

In a dataset like this: (y is angle and x is datapoints)

[image]

How to find the weighted average of each "band" (in that case would be 0.1 and -90 something) whilst ignoring potential random points.

I was thinking of the FFT transform but that might not be the right approach.

Perhaps transforming that in a graph alike normal distribution and find the peaks?

Comment: You could use [KMeans clustering](https://towardsdatascience.com/machine-learning-algorithms-part-9-k-means-example-in-python-f2ad05ed5203) with specifying two clusters.

Comment: I went across that but seems to be for x,y type of dataset @DarrylG

Comment: @Damien--added answer showing how kmeans can be used.  The trick is to use reshape to convert 1D array so it can be used by KMeans as shown in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solve Using [KMeans](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.KMeans.html)

**Step 1. Generate Data**

```
from random import randint, choice
from numpy import random
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def gen_pts(mean_, std_, n):
  """Generate gaussian distributed random data
     mean: mean_
    standard deviation: std_
    number points: n
  """
  return np.random.normal(loc=mean_, scale = std_, size = n)

# Number of groups of horizontal blobs
n_groups = 20

# Genereate random count for each group
counts = [randint(100, 200) for _ in range(n_groups)]

# Generate random mean for each group (i.e. 0 or -90)
means = [random.choice([0, -90]) for _ in range(n_groups)]

# All the groups
data = [gen_pts(mean_, 5, n) for mean_, n in zip(means, counts)]

# Concatenate groups into 1D array
X = np.concatenate(data, axis=0)

# Show Data
plt.plot(X)
plt.show()
```

[image]

**Step 2-Find Cluster Centers**

```
# Reshape 1D data so it's suitable for kmeans model
X = X.reshape(-1,1)

# Get model for two clusters
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init='k-means++', max_iter=300, n_init=10, random_state=0)

# Fit Data to model
pred_y = kmeans.fit_predict(X)

# Cluster Centers
centers = kmeans.cluster_centers_
print(*centers)
# Output: [-89.79165334] [-0.07875314]
```